# Can Gulp signalize to Docker about complete first iteration of incremental building?

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp

Below command expresses: "once Gulp task 'developmentBuild' complete,  start the Docker":

```
gulp developmentBuild && docker compose -up
```

However, the tasks for the local development mode like `developmetBuild` usually never ends because they are using the file watchers and will be wait for the changes until the process will be killed or critical error will occur. The `developmetBuild` could be something like:

```
gulp.task('developmetBuild', ['browser-sync', 'css-libs', 'scripts'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);проекта
    gulp.watch(['app/js/common.js', 'app/libs/**/*.js'], browserSync.reload);
});
```

What about the parallel run?

```
gulp developmentBuild & docker compose -up
```

Sometimes it will not work. For example, in the below case, the `nodemon` must be started only when `FrontServerEntryPoint` has been built.

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  FrontServer:

    image: node:16-alpine
    container_name: Example-Local-FrontServer
    ports: [ "8080:8080" ]

    # [ Theory ] Nodemon will not be found if invoke just "nodemon". See https://linuxpip.org/nodemon-not-found/
    # [ Theory ] About -L flag: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1802
    command: sh -c "cd var/www/example.com && node_modules/.bin/nodemon -L 03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/FrontServerEntryPoint.js --environment local"

    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=Database

    depends_on: [ Database ]

    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /var/www/example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, in the below case, the nodemon must be started only when FrontServerEntryPoint has been built.

That means you need two steps:

- one for building (without [watcher](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/watching-files#warning-avoid-synchronous))
- one for the parallel run

That is:

```js
gulp.task('initialBuild', ['css-libs', 'scripts']);

gulp.task('developmentBuild', ['initialBuild', 'browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(['app/js/common.js', 'app/libs/**/*.js'], browserSync.reload);
});
```

Which you can run with `gulp initialBuild && (gulp developmentBuild & docker-compose up)`

The '`developmentBuild`' task has '`initialBuild`' and '`browser-sync`' as its dependencies.
This means that '`initialBuild`' and '`browser-sync`' tasks will run *before* the '`developmentBuild`' task starts executing the function containing the watchers.

---

As an alternative approach, you can try and use `child_process.exec` (after `npm install child_process`) in Node.js to run the initial build and then run Docker Compose and the Gulp watcher in parallel.

`node run-build-and-compose.js`:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('gulp initialBuild', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`initialBuild error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`initialBuild output: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`initialBuild stderr: ${stderr}`);

  // Run the Gulp developmentBuild task and Docker Compose in parallel
  const devBuild = exec('gulp developmentBuild');
  devBuild.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`developmentBuild output: ${data}`);
  });
  devBuild.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`developmentBuild stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  const dockerCompose = exec('docker-compose up');
  dockerCompose.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Docker Compose output: ${data}`);
  });
  dockerCompose.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`Docker Compose stderr: ${data}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it the only one solution?

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD Maybe one alternative approach would be to use `child_process.exec` in Node.js to run the initial build and then run Docker Compose and the Gulp watcher in parallel. What is problematic in my initial proposed approach?

Comment: "Maybe one alternative" - got it, maybe I'll ask the other question about it. Thank you again. "What is problematic in my initial proposed approach?" - no problems if we have the simple Gulp preset. However the main approach you suggested could not be easily integrate to [my Gulp-based utility](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-Automation) so some alternatives required.

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD OK. I have edited the answer to include said alternative approach.

Comment: Thank you very much. Upvote & accept & reputation prize.